# Deploying laravel php app with pgsql on heroku

Tags: php, postgresql, laravel, heroku

I am trying to deploy laravel php app on heroku,the app deployed perfectly without DB but when i try to add the postgresql addon in my application it doesnt show any error in the cmd and also i have a login and register page, both are also working prefectly,I am able to register and login without any problem.

But he problem is when i try to open any other pages that is connected to dB. it shows the error on my browser

"Whoops, looks like something went wrong."

I am not getting any other errors.i dont know what is happening.
If somebody can help.thanks

The steps i adopted to deply are.

```
$ git init
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "new laravel project"


$echo web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 public/ > Procfile
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "Procfile for Heroku"

$heroku create

$ heroku config:set APP_KEY= key
$git push heroku master
```

now for the pgsql i did..

```
 $ heroku addons:add heroku-postgresql:hobby-dev

$ heroku config
```

Changed the value of 'default' in app/config/database.php to 'pgsql'.

```
'default' => 'pgsql',
```

At the top of  database.php:

```
$url = parse_url(getenv("DATABASE_URL"));

$host = $url["host"];
$username = $url["user"];
$password = $url["pass"];
$database = substr($url["path"], 1);
```

Then change your pgsql entry in that same file to be the following:

```
'pgsql' => array(
    'driver'   => 'pgsql',
    'host'     => $host,
    'database' => $database,
    'username' => $username,
    'password' => $password,
    'charset'  => 'utf8',
    'prefix'   => '',
    'schema'   => 'public',
),


$ git add .
$ git commit -m "Convert to use Heroku PostgreSQL database"
$ git push heroku master
$ heroku run php artisan migrate
```

Comment: can you provide the log when you get the error?

Comment: how can i get the error log?

Comment: It will be in project root folder. See `storage/logs/laravel.log` or  `storage/logs/{date}.log`

Comment: yeah thanks but i am not able to get it from the heroku server..

Comment: Try to run application in debug mode to know the specific error.

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: host in C:\xampp\htdocs\soviga-tool1\config\database.php on line 5

Notice: Undefined index: user in C:\xampp\htdocs\soviga-tool1\config\database.php on line 6

Notice: Undefined index: pass in C:\xampp\htdocs\soviga-tool1\config\database.php on line 7

Comment: getiing these..

Comment: and also the application is running with no new entry in log file

Comment: It seems that your `DATABASE_URL` is empty. It's causing the issue. To verify what `$url` consist you can `var_dump(getenv('DATABASE_URL'));`

Comment: yes its empty..but why is the login and register page working?and also when i enter  $ heroku config it shows the databse_url.

Comment: Now instead of using the url.i changed the .env file with the credentials. and know i am getting this error...

Comment: QueryException in Connection.php line 729:
SQLSTATE[42P01]: Undefined table: 7 ERROR: relation "buisnessArea" does not exist
LINE 1: select * from "buisnessArea"
^ (SQL: select * from "buisnessArea")

Comment: its working know thanks.

Comment: Go to Settings on your project page on Heroku, and add a config variable for `APP_LOG` set to `errorlog`. You will now see exceptions in `heroku logs`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem when I tried to deploy my test project in heroku recently. Lately I found out that there's a problem in my *Procfile*

```
web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 public/
```

The problem in the procfile I think is heroku php-apache2 builder changed. So what I did is delete my *Procfile* file and let heroku configured my app with it's default Procfile for php, and the result Procfile was

```
web: heroku-php-apache2 web/
```

So, that's it. I created another Procfile with the **public/** folder for Laravel App.

```
web: heroku-php-apahce2 public/
```

And it's working now.

Also with regards to DB connection. I didn't change my .env file, what I did is configure the config vars in Settings page and manually input the required DB connection parameters there.

I just followed these url format for postgresql server in heroku.

```
dialect+driver://username:password@host:port/database
```